# How to run a query between dates and times?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a query where I need to pull information from two different dates and times.
I want to pull everything that was date last modified between yesterday and today and between the time last modified of 18:00:00 hours from yesterday and 13:00:00 hours of today.

How can I accomplish this?

```
  SELECT A1.CHCASN, 
         A1.CHTRKN,
         SUM(A2.CDPAKU) AS UNITS, 
         A1.CHACWT, 
         SUM(A2.CDPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS COST, 
         SUM(A3.STRPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS RETAIL, 
         A1.CHDLM, 
         A1.CHTLM
    FROM CHCART00 A1, 
         CDCART00 A2, 
         STSTYL00 A3
   WHERE A1.CHCASN = A2.CDCASN
     AND A2.CDSTYL = A3.STSTYL
     AND A2.CDCOLR = A3.STCOLR
     AND A2.CDSDIM = A3.STSDIM
     AND A1.CHSTAT = '25'
     AND A1.CHROUT = 'UPSCA'
     AND A1.CHDLM BETWEEN 20110505 And 20110506
     AND A1.CHTLM >= '160000'
     AND A1.CHTLM <= '130000'
GROUP BY A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, A1.CHACWT, A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM
ORDER BY A1.CHCASN
```

Comment: BTW Nice naming conventions....

Comment: "Legacy", like the column names, has only six letters.

Comment: How can something be `>=16` AND `<=13` at the same time?

Comment: these are times and they are for different dates. The >=16000 is for date 20110505 and <=130000 is for today 20110506.

Comment: Are these two columns (CHDLM and CHTLM) timestamps, dates, integers, chars or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
 AND ( A1.CHDLM = 20110505 
       AND A1.CHTLM >= '160000' 
     OR
       A1.CHDLM = 20110506
       AND A1.CHTLM <= '130000'
     )
```

---

For more generality (to catch the case when the two dates are not consecutive), it should be:

```
 AND ( A1.CHDLM = 20110505 
       AND A1.CHTLM >= '160000' 
     OR
       A1.CHDLM BETWEEN 20110505 +1
                    AND 20110506 -1
     OR
       A1.CHDLM = 20110506
       AND A1.CHTLM <= '130000'
     )
```

Comment: Hello! I'm facing an issue on this query. When try to change the date for a bigger range it doesn't work