# Query with date range and specific times range?

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange

I have this query for a DB2 DB where I need to pull data between dates and specific times. I came up with the query below and it is working but is not getting the data for the day in between 20110510 and 20110512 in this case 20110511, this data should be for the entire day.

The dates and times are user's parameters so this will change depending on their needs. I also want to be able to pull data for the same day with the same query if possible, for example:

```
Date last modify >= 20110512 AND
Date last modify <= 20110512 AND
Time last modify >= 090000   AND
Time last modify <= 230000   AND
```

Any help will be really appreciate it in advance. Thank you.

```
SELECT A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN,
SUM(A2.CDPAKU) AS UNITS, A1.CHACWT, SUM(A2.CDPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS COST, SUM(A3.STRPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS RETAIL, A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM
FROM CHCART00 A1, CDCART00 A2, STSTYL00 A3
WHERE A1.CHCASN = A2.CDCASN
AND A2.CDSTYL = A3.STSTYL
AND A2.CDCOLR = A3.STCOLR
AND A2.CDSDIM = A3.STSDIM
AND A1.CHSTAT = '25'
AND (A1.CHDLM = 20110510 AND A1.CHTLM >= '200000' OR A1.CHDLM = 20110512 AND A1.CHTLM <= '092000') AND A1.CHROUT = 'UPSPA'
GROUP BY A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, A1.CHACWT, A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM
ORDER BY A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM
```

Comment: Ambiguous -- First, the initial date test probably should test against 20110511 for the first date. (Typo?) But then, because dates and times are separately tested, actual requirement seems to be "between 9:00AM and 11:00PM on **each** date in the range". If so, then TIMESTAMPs to specify begin and end of a range wouldn't work. What's the actual requirement? The SQL seems to imply that TIMESTAMPs could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples:-

(Between two dates)

```
`SELECT A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, SUM(A2.CDPAKU) AS UNITS, A1.CHACWT,
    SUM(A2.CDPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS COST, SUM(A3.STRPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS RETAIL,     
    A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM FROM CHCART00 A1, CDCART00 A2, STSTYL00 A3  
WHERE A1.CHCASN = A2.CDCASN AND A2.CDSTYL = A3.STSTYL AND      
    A2.CDCOLR = A3.STCOLR     AND A2.CDSDIM = A3.STSDIM AND A1.CHSTAT = '25' AND
    (A1.CHDLM BETWEEN 20110510 AND 20110512)      
    AND A1.CHROUT = 'UPSPA' GROUP BY A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, A1.CHACWT,
    A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM  
ORDER BY A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM`
```

(Same date)

```
`SELECT A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, SUM(A2.CDPAKU) AS UNITS, A1.CHACWT,
    SUM(A2.CDPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS COST, SUM(A3.STRPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS RETAIL,     
    A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM FROM CHCART00 A1, CDCART00 A2, STSTYL00 A3  
WHERE A1.CHCASN = A2.CDCASN AND A2.CDSTYL = A3.STSTYL AND      
    A2.CDCOLR = A3.STCOLR     AND A2.CDSDIM = A3.STSDIM AND A1.CHSTAT = '25' AND
    (A1.CHDLM = 20110511)     
    AND A1.CHROUT = 'UPSPA' GROUP BY A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, A1.CHACWT,
    A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM  
ORDER BY A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM `
```

Comment: What about the time range? how would you accommodate that in the query? I've try many different ways but no luck A1.CHTLM >= '200000' AND A1.CHTLM <= '092000'.

Comment: If you really need the times as well, then the best solution would be to have the WHERE clause structured along the lines of 

`...AND ((A1.CHDLM=20110510 AND A1.CHTLM>=092000) --This is the start of the range 
OR (A1.CHDLM BETWEEN 20110511 AND 20110511) --This is the middle of the range (not always required) 
OR (A1.CHDLM=20110512 AND A1.CHTLM<=110000)) --This is the end of the range`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some parentheses from your WHERE clause

Try this:-

```
SELECT A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, SUM(A2.CDPAKU) AS UNITS, A1.CHACWT, 
    SUM(A2.CDPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS COST, SUM(A3.STRPRC * A2.CDPAKU) AS RETAIL,
    A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM FROM CHCART00 A1, CDCART00 A2, STSTYL00 A3 
WHERE A1.CHCASN = A2.CDCASN AND A2.CDSTYL = A3.STSTYL AND 
    A2.CDCOLR = A3.STCOLR AND A2.CDSDIM = A3.STSDIM AND A1.CHSTAT = '25' AND
    ((A1.CHDLM = 20110510 AND A1.CHTLM >= '200000') 
    OR
    (A1.CHDLM = 20110511)
    OR
    (A1.CHDLM = 20110512 AND A1.CHTLM <= '092000')) 
    AND A1.CHROUT = 'UPSPA' GROUP BY A1.CHCASN, A1.CHTRKN, A1.CHACWT, 
    A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM 
ORDER BY A1.CHDLM, A1.CHTLM
```

Comment: No it didn't work. I'm still missing all the data for 20110511

Comment: My bad - if you read the WHERE clause, it is stating that it wants the records where CHDLM is 20110510 and the time is anything after 8pm OR the CHDLM is 20110512 and the time is before 9:20am. I have edited the answer to include the DLM for 20110511, regardless of time. Please could you try the revised version.

Comment: Ok, this one worked just fine but what if there is more dates in between. Let's say for example I wanted to see everything between 20110505 and 20110512 using the same time range. do I have to specify each date in between? I don't want to make the user type in all those different dates.. Thank you in advance

Comment: Would this query work if I use the same dates in the date range? Like CHDLM = 20110512 and CHDLM = 20110512 thank you.

Comment: You can use the BETWEEN operator
`A1.CHDML BETWEEN 20110505 AND 20110512`

Comment: If you are using the same date then the WHERE clause simply becomes
`A1.CHDLM = 20110512` without the ANDs and ORs surrounding it.

Comment: Ok, I tried that but the time is not being taken into consideration when the query runs because is giving me everything for the date range it's ignoring the time. How can I accomplish this with the specific times. Thank you.

Comment: @jorame: Haven't I answered this already at this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917103/how-to-run-a-query-between-dates-and-times/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to combine the date and time columns into a timestamp or a similar structure that is much easier to use for ranged searches across multiple days. It doesn't really matter what data type is used; just be sure it follows some sort of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format and convert your input parameter(s) the same way so they can be compared with the column data.

Assumptions:

- Column CHDLM column in table CHCART00 is INTEGER and stores dates in YYYYMMDD format
- Column CHTLM column in table CHCART00 is CHAR(6) and stores times in 24hr HHMMSS format
- The window specified by the input parameters is continuous, with no gaps such as "business hours only"

  `AND ( BIGINT( A1.CHDLM ) * 1000000 + INTEGER( A1.CHTLM ))`

  `>= ( BIGINT( 20110510 ) * 1000000 + INTEGER('230000'))`

  `AND ( BIGINT( A1.CHDLM ) * 1000000 + INTEGER( A1.CHTLM ))`

  `<= ( BIGINT( 20110512 ) * 1000000 + INTEGER('090000'))`

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to pull the query is this :

```
SELECT
  num_executions,
  num_exec_with_metrics,
  SUBSTR(stmt_text,1,2000000) AS stmt_text
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT('d', null, null, -1)) AS tf
WHERE
  (VARCHAR_FORMAT(INSERT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > '2016-01-27 07:00:00'
  AND VARCHAR_FORMAT(INSERT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= '2016-01-27 08:59:59')
ORDER BY INSERT_TIMESTAMP DESC;
```

Comment: Instead of posting some code without explanation, consider rewriting the question asker's SQL statement.